# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' - this error is keep showing even though one time it shows the price

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075CYMYK6?ref_=cm_sw_r_cp_ud_ct_FM9M699VKHTT47YD50Q6&th=1'
header = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/118.0.2088.24",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
}

responce = requests.get(URL, headers = header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.content, "lxml")

# print(soup.prettify())`your text

price = soup.find(class\_="a-price-whole").get_text()
print(price)
```

i only want this output  - $52.00`

Comment: *Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.*  Amazon do not like to automated traffic in any way, so it try to block it if recognised, so you should check this first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the selector:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075CYMYK6?ref_=cm_sw_r_cp_ud_ct_FM9M699VKHTT47YD50Q6&th=1"
header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/118.0.2088.24",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
}

responce = requests.get(URL, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.content, "lxml")

price = soup.find(class_="a-offscreen").get_text()
print(price)
```

Prints:

```
$98.07
```